# Numeric conversion

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

In the  header of C++11, there are three new functions for conversion between number and string.

```
std::string std::to_string(unsigned long long);
std::string std::to_string(long double);
std::string std::to_string(long long);
```

The first question - why there is only 3 functions? What about simple int or unsigned int, etc.?

The second question - why to_string doesn't throw exception in following code?

```
long double x = std::numeric_limits<long double>::quiet_NaN();
std::string i = std::to_string( x ); 
long double c = std::stold( i ); // i = "1.#QNAN"
```

And the third question - why c equals 1.0 ?

Comment: wild guess, but maybe only those three exist because the smaller integer and floating point types can be easily converted to them without loss of information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **"*As long as it yields the behavior described, do what you please..*"**

  All intrinsic numeric types can implicitly be converted to either `unsigned long long`, `long double` or `long long` and still hold the precision required, therefore no more overloads are necessary.

  The standard says that the following functions should be defined, though a lib confirming to the standard is free to do "*whatever it wants*" as long as it yields the same behavior as described.

---

- **Why should it throw an exception?**

  `std::numeric_limits<long double>::quiet_NaN();` is a valid value, and `std::to_string (T)` is described in the standard to yield the same behavior as calling `sprintf` with the appropriate *format-string*.

> **§ 21.5**/6                   **Numeric conversions**
>
> - `string to_string(int val);`
> - `string to_string(unsigned val);`
> - `string to_string(long val);`
> - `string to_string(unsigned long val);`
> - `string to_string(long long val);`
> - `string to_string(unsigned long long val);`
> - `string to_string(float val);`
> - `string to_string(double val);`
> - `string to_string(long double val);`
>
>   <sup>..</sup>
>
> **Returns:**
>
> - Each function returns a string object holding the character
>     representation of the value of its argument that would be generated by
>     calling sprintf(buf, fmt, val) with a format specifier of "*%d*", "*%u*",
>     "*%ld*", "*%lu*", "*%lld*", "*%llu*", "*%f*", "*%f*", or "*%Lf*", respectively,
>     where buf designates an internal character buffer of sufficient size.

---

- <strike>**On what compiler is `c` equal to `1.0`?**</strike>

  The conversion should yield a `NaN`-value if the value of `i` is string representation of `NaN` (not containing any digits).

  If no suitable conversion can be found the function is described to throw `invalid_argument`.

  *MSVC* will yield `1.#QNAN` when trying to convert `std::numeric_limits<long double>::quiet_NaN();` to a `std::string`.

  When using `std::stold` it will look for the first none whitespace character, and then use as many digits as found (in this case only `1`), therefore `c` will be equal to `1.0` after the function call.

Answer (score 1):

I find the whole package in my copy of the standard:

```
string to_string(int val);
string to_string(unsigned val);
string to_string(long val);
string to_string(unsigned long val);
string to_string(long long val);
string to_string(unsigned long long val);
string to_string(float val);
string to_string(double val);
string to_string(long double val);
```

Perhaps your compiler just hasn't implemented all of them yet?

The functionality is described as

> Returns: Each function returns a string object holding the character representation of the value of its argument that would be generated by calling `sprintf(buf, fmt, val)` with a format specifier of `"%d"`, `"%u"`, `"%ld"`, `"%lu"`, `"%lld"`, `"%llu"`, `"%f"`, `"%f"`, or `"%Lf"`, respectively, where `buf` designates an internal character buffer of sufficient size.

As it is supposed to be a wrapper around `sprintf` it was probably decided not to throw any exceptions, as `sprintf` does not.

Comment: I'm using visual C++ & msvc2010.

Comment: I belive the additional functions were added to the standard at a late stage, because people like you asked for them. VC2010 was released before that.

Comment: Strange.  I wonder why they didn't wrap std::ostringstream or std::istringstream?

Comment: I wish to see lexical_cast in std namespace :)